# Why do the eyes of a bounded soul glow?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series

If I didn't miss one, all souls that were bound to armors have glowing eyes.

[image: Slicer brothers]
[image: Barry the chopper]
[image: Alphonse Elric]

Why do their eyes glow? It must somehow be connected to the bounded soul, as they stop glowing if the heads lose connection to the rest of the armor, but how? And can they still see, if the head is loose?

Source of the images: [Fullmetal Alchemist Wiki](http://fma.wikia.com)

Comment: Related: http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3547/274 ... Also, note that this is not wholly true: It is later revealed that Slicer is in fact two people; the second does not have eyes at all. (It seems to only affect helmets.)

Comment: @Eric yeah, I also noticed that. But still, it seems like he can see something ...

Comment: Yes, he can, as the soul is basically combined with the armor to form one cohesive unit. (Take a look at [this question](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3854/274). It's not an exact explanation, but you have to give some credit to creative liberty.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In many cultures, the eyes are regarded as the doorway/path to your soul. Therefore, in many ways, eyes are often manipulated to show the will/emotions/drive of the creature in question (and by creature, I include animals, aliens, humans, anime-pseudo-beings and all other lifeforms that are shown with eyes).

In contrast, what does not have eyes, we often perceive as dead. Even creatures that are presented without eyes, often carry a bandage og other device covering the area where the eyes would normally be shown.

To give life and passion to a character in a show, they have to be designed with eyes or other seemingly visual-oriented details.

Also notice: Often bigger eyes are pictured as more passionate, while small/tiny eyes are often used to convey negative traits.